# test rxjava callback function

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java2

I'm trying to test the code written in callback function of one of Rxjava operator. Here is the original code that I want to test

```
@Override
public Observable<List<User>> getUsers() {
    UserDataStore userDataStore = userDataStoreFactory.createCloudDataStore();
    return userDataStore.getUsers().map(userEntityDataMapper::transform);
}
```

In above code there is a "map" operator and its callback Function will transform the original object to another by calling `userEntityDataMapper.transform()` method. **Here I want to test that userEntityDataMapper's transform method must be call.** Here is the code which I tried to check if `userEntityDataMapper.transform()` method calls or not.

```
@Test
public void testGetUsersHappyCase() {
    List<UserEntity> userEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
    userEntityList.add(new UserEntity());
    given(mockUserDataStore.getUsers()).willReturn(Observable.just(userEntityList));
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    given(mockUserEntityDataMapper.transform(userEntityList)).willReturn(userList);
    given(mockUserDataStoreFactory.createCloudDataStore()).willReturn(mockUserDataStore);

    Observable observable = userDataRepository.getUsers();

    verify(mockUserDataStoreFactory).createCloudDataStore();
    verify(mockUserDataStore).getUsers();
    TestObserver<List<UserEntity>> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    observable.subscribeOn(testScheduler).observeOn(testScheduler).subscribeWith(testObserver);
    verify(mockUserEntityDataMapper).transform(any(List.class));
}
```

I checked many similar questions on stackoverflow and from forum but not able to find exact solution for my question.

**Update:**
Here is the change which I did to fix the problem.

```
@Test
public void testGetUsersHappyCase() {
    List<UserEntity> userEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
    userEntityList.add(new UserEntity());
    given(mockUserDataStore.getUsers()).willReturn(Observable.just(userEntityList));
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    given(mockUserEntityDataMapper.transform(userEntityList)).willReturn(userList);

    userDataRepository.getUsers().test().assertNoErrors();

    verify(mockUserDataStoreFactory).createCloudDataStore();
    verify(mockUserDataStore).getUsers();

    verify(mockUserEntityDataMapper).transform(userEntityList);
}
```

Thanks @tynn for the hint of test() method. Also same thing I found in BasicRxJavaSample demo found on https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components.

Comment: What do you get in logs?

Comment: So what's your issue? If this tests fails you'll also have a message. Please post it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the stream in order to execute it. This can be done as easily as calling [`test()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#test--) on the observable. This will provide you with a `TestObserver`.

Additional to this, you don't have any reason to use a `TestScheduler`. In your case it's actually the issue. You're not calling to `triggerActions()` and thus your stream is not executed at all.

If you don't modify any scheduler in the code you're testing, just ignore these in your tests as well. If you need to change it, you should better create a rule to set the [`Schedulers`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html) to a synchronous version each. You find setters for this with the [`RxJavaPlugins`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/plugins/RxJavaPlugins.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

[Tynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385212/tynn)'s answer is correct and you should listen to the advice there. The refactored test looks something like this:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testUserDataRepository() throws Exception {
    //arrange
    List<UserEntity> userEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
    userEntityList.add(new UserEntity());
    given(mockUserDataStore.getUsers()).willReturn(Observable.just(userEntityList));
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    given(mockUserEntityDataMapper.transform(userEntityList)).willReturn(userList);
    given(mockUserDataStoreFactory.createCloudDataStore()).willReturn(mockUserDataStore);

    //act
    TestObserver<List<User>> testObservable = userDataRepository.getUsers().test();


    //assert
    verify(mockUserDataStoreFactory).createCloudDataStore();
    verify(mockUserDataStore).getUsers();
    verify(mockUserEntityDataMapper).transform(any(List.class));
}
```

However there is a greater problem with this type of white box test - the test has degenerated into a reimplementation of the system under test.

If `UserEntityDataMapper` is lightweight you can use a real version of it in your test. Then your test becomes a black box test and arguably has more value. You will know that the call to `UserEntityDataMapper#transform` has occurred through the assertion on the correct result of `List<User>`:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testUserDataRepository() throws Exception {
    //arrange
    List<UserEntity> userEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
    userEntityList.add(new UserEntity());
    given(mockUserDataStore.getUsers()).willReturn(Observable.just(userEntityList));
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    given(mockUserDataStoreFactory.createCloudDataStore()).willReturn(mockUserDataStore);

    //act
    TestObserver<List<User>> testObservable = userDataRepository.getUsers().test();

    //assert
    testObservable.assertResult(userList);
}
```

Comment: [David Rawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5241933/david-rawson) Great idea, but how it will be matched the result of real version without providing the real version of result data(in this case List<User>)? UserEntityDataMapper#transform has lots of code to convert each fields of UserEntity to User class and append into the list

Comment: @Dharmendra you could supply a fake `List<UserEntity>` and run the real `UserEntityDataMapper#transform` on it to generate the expected `List<User>` or, even better, construct the generated list manually. Constructing the expected `List<User>` manually will be the better kind of black box test as your expected result will be independent of the test steps

Comment: But I guess this can be cover when we write tests for UserEntityDataMapper class itself. so writing the tests for UserEntityDataMapper will be the actual testing of the transform method and will it not be consider as a black box testing?